# how to run macro i recorded for entire column to another column without code?

Tags: excel

in Excel I have 22000 rows with '0' formatted as text. I can select entire column and click 'convert to number'.

but excel freezes for a long time. 
I found a way to do it simpler:

- insert 1 as a digit to any cell
- copy it
- insert to the top cell of the column of zeros
- select till the end of column, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>alt</kbd> - <kbd>v</kbd> for smart insert
- select option 'multiply'

Made a macros for it. Now how do i make it work for another entire column of zeros? 
I press the hotkey , and it just replaces the current cell with 1

Comment: `With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    .Value = .Value
End With`

Comment: Pl refer <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771458/vba-convert-text-to-number> and < https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375034/converting-a-certain-range-of-columns-from-text-to-number-format-with-vba>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open VBA by pressing together <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> keys.
All your recorded macros will be present Under Folder `VBAProject > Modules`.

[image: VBA Screenshot]

You can change the required column in your macro and then again run using the shortcut or Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to execute the macro.

**Update:**
You can use the below code snippet to add custom column range, which the user will input for the macro to execute on.

```vb
Dim rngCol As Range
Set rngCol = Application.InputBox("Pick Column Range: ", , , , , , , 8)
```

Comment: how do i apply to current selected column? this seems like hardcoding it. macros is useful when i automate sequence of actions

Comment: Please check the updated answer in which you can have an input box to select the range on which you want to execute the macro.